# php Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AppMailCore in /appmail.core.php on line 10

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm getting this error when I run the script

```
php Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class AppMailCore in /appmail.core.php on line 10
```

I need to make loop that will also use some variables from a class file . The code from main.php looks like this :

```
   $iesc = 1;
 while($iesc less than 5)
{
include('includes/appmail.core.php');
---
```

I used "less than " in the code above 'cause I don't know to unescape "<" symbold within the pre markup .

I understand that I'm  not allowed to re-delcare the class but I don't know how to make the class variables run through the loop .
appmail.core.php looks like this

```
require_once('appmail.config.php');
require_once('helpers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'appmail.rest.php');

class AppMailCore
{
  var $AppMailRest;
  var $api_key;
  var $url;

  /**
   * Initialises AppMailCore. Optionally provide runtime api key and url.
   */
  function AppMailCore($api_key = APPMAIL_API_KEY, $url = APPMAIL_URL) {
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->api_key = $api_key;
    $this->AppMailRest = new AppMailRest($this->url);
  }

  /**
   * Asynchronously sends an email using Google App Engine
   *
   * Params are fairly self explanatory. However, note that the "from" address must be a registered email with
   * your Google App Engine account.
   */
  function send($to, $from, $subject, $plain, $html) {
    $api_key = $this->api_key;
    $status = $this->AppMailRest->post('send', compact('api_key','to','from','subject','plain','html'));
    return $status;
  }
}
```

the appmail.config.php loooks like this

```
  $app1DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ast");
  $app1RSP = $app1DB->query("SELECT app_id FROM Application WHERE emails_sent fetch_assoc();
    $app_id = $app1Object['app_id'];


define('APPMAIL_API_KEY', 'JLQ7P5SnTPq7AJvLnUysJmXSeXTrhgaJ');
define('APPMAIL_URL', "http://$app_id.appspot.com/");

   $app1RSP->free();
   $app1DB->close();
```

Basically I need to get variable APPMAIL_URL/$app_id in the class on each loop run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you doing the `include` before the loop ?

Another tip: use `include_once` ?

Third tip: include directly `appmail.config.php` if you need a constant from it, not `appmail.core.php` ?

**EDIT**

> Basically I need to get variable
>   APPMAIL_URL/$app_id in the class on
>   each loop run.

If its value is supposed to change through the script execution (as I just saw), then you shouldn't define it as a constant.

Comment: @Frosty Z If I include the appmail.core.php before the loop I think I'm getting the same APPMAIL_URL(which is in the appmail.config.php )  on each loop as it will be retrieved only once from the db . I need to get different APPMAIL_URL on each loop .

Comment: @Michael: then your object is defined wrong. Define/initiate the object once, then reset the APPMAIL_URL on each iteration.

Comment: @Frosty Z can you please elaborate your answer or provide some code? . I've tried 100 methods today and couldn't make it work .. mostly 'cause I don't have a very good OOP understanding I think :(

Comment: @Marc B how can I reset the APPMAIL_URL  ? that's all I need.. to reset the APPMAIL_URL based on the $app_id retrieved from database.  I don't have a very good OOP understanding .

Comment: I finally figured out how to fix it .. thanks a lot for your help !